# Kovan transaction never being mined

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js

I have set up an Infura account to send transactions on the kovan network.
This is the code I want to use to send ether to another account (current one has 1 ether from a faucet):

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3('wss://kovan.infura.io/ws/v3/<PK>');
var Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx');

target = '<target address 0x>'
priv = '<priv key  0x>'
address = '<from account  0x>'
a = web3.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount(priv);

web3.eth.defaultAccount = address

const EthereumTx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction
const privateKey = Buffer.from(
  priv,
  'hex',
)

wei = 1000000000000000000
price = 5000000000

const txParams = {
  nonce: '0x19',
  gasPrice: "0x" + Math.floor(price).toString(16),
  gasLimit: "0x" + (wei * 0.05 / price).toString(16),
  to: target,
  value: "0x100",
}

const tx = new EthereumTx(txParams)
tx.sign(privateKey)

var serializedTx = tx.serialize();

web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'))
  .on('receipt', console.log);
```

But the transaction never gets mined, no matter how high I set the gas limit. I eventually get this message

> (node:28855) **UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning**: Error: Transaction was not mined within 50 blocks, please make sure your transaction was properly sent. Be aware that it might still be mined!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: i think you will have a better chance to get an answer if you ask here https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Are you sure that you've set the nonce correctly? If it's too high, your transaction won't be mined.

Comment: I made a new account with a 0 nonce. It still doesn't work